# Proving Dirichlet test in which given sequence is monotonic increasing sequence converging to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question** if $(b_n)$ is monotone increasing sequence converging to $0$ and sequence of partial sum $(s_n)$ of series $\sum_{i=1}^∞ a_n$ is bounded then $\sum_{i=1}^∞ a_nb_n$ is convergent.

I had proved this test for the case when $(b_n)$ is decreasing sequence converging to $0$.

But here it is increasing sequence converging to $0$. **So how can i establish absolute convergence of** $\sum_{k=1}^∞ s_k(b_k-b_{k+1})$
Please help.

Comment: Let $c_n = -b_n$ and $d_n = -a_n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you so..much sir. I got it. Let $(t_n)$ be sequence of partial sum of $\sum_{i=1}^∞ a_n$ then $t_n=a_1b_1+ ...+a_nb_n$ and hence $t_n= -d_1b_1+(d_1-d_2)b_2+...+(d_{n-1}-d_n)b_n = -d_1b_1-(d_2-d_1)b_2-...-(d_{n}-d_{n-1})b_n$ and hence $t_n= d_1c_1+(d_2-d_1)c_2+...+(d_n-d_{n-1})c_n= d_1(c_1-c_2)+d_2(c_2-c_3)+...+d_n(c_n-c_{n+1})+ d_nc_{n+1}$ so that $t_n =\sum_{k=1}^n d_k(c_k -c_{k+1}) +d_n c_{n+1}$ and from here rest of the proof is same as it was for previous case in which $(b_n)$ is decreasing.

Comment: Another option is to note $\lvert s_k(b_k - b_{k+1})\rvert = \lvert s_k\rvert(b_{k+1} - b_k)$.